# Size of drop-down arrow is smaller then usual

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox

The dropdown arrow of Jquery-UI Combobox is not looking like they promised.

I have downloaded all the Jquery-UI code from their website and included in my websites directory.

```
<head>
    <title>TAT Dashboard</title>
    <link href="dist/css/customStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/funnelStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/uploaderStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/dropdownStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

    <link href="dist/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


    <!-- Jquery UI JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



    <!-- Resources for charts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/d3-funnel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/funnelScript2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/dropdown.js"></script>


</head>
```

Observer the arrows.
They should be of the same size as the textbox.

I expected this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxZmc.jpg

But I am getting this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGVVH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by reordering the declarations & removing some redundant ones to avoid clashes.
@ross has helped in critically thinking the problem in hand. Here is the declaration.

```
<link href="dist/css/customStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/funnelStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/uploaderStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/dropdownStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .custom-combobox {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .custom-combobox-toggle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-left: -1px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .custom-combobox-input {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/dropdown.js"></script>

    <!-- Resources for charts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/d3-funnel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/funnelScript2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `line-height` of the icons:

```
.icons{line-height: 20px;}
```

Comment: I tried this but they still do not appear to be inline. I think we should not mess with the framework variables as they are working perfectly as in docs [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)
I have a strong feeling that the Jquery & UI libraries I am loading are not in sync.

Comment: Target them by using your own classes didn't effect default libraries styles, it just override it, Can you provide me a fiddle or a code-pen of your code

Comment: my bad. Actually, it was working somehow is firefox. See the update [here](https://jsfiddle.net/opankajkumar/rja1xqn3/5/)
Observe that the dropdown is also appearing at the left-top corner. Wierd.